# Error during transaction commit. Null

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

Update: I've figured out it is because I have a 'Link' in my schema, I want the field 'createdBy' to link to the OUser class of the user, but I can't seem to make that link. Somehow when the function creates the V it doesn't inherit the field type from the class. Any ideas?

-

I've got an issue writing using functions. I want to write to the Database but I cant. if I commit using the normal orient.getGraph() I get the following error: (OrientDB Version 2.0.7)

```
Error on parsing script at position #0: Error on execution of the script
Script: newConcept
------^
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Error during transaction commit. (
<Unknown source>#26) in 

    <Unknown source> at line number 26
Wrapped com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Error during transaction commit. (
        <Unknown source>#26)
Error during transaction commit.
null
```

And if I try it with the non-transactional it just doesn't write.

I am sending a post request, I've tried enabling Javascript server side scripting but that is not the issue.

Here is my whole function:

```javascript
var graph = orient.getGraph();
var currentUserId = getCurrentUserId();
var currentTimeStamp = getCurrentDateString();

//Check if the className is not specified or if the class does not exist.
if(graph.getVertexType(className)==null){
 //return an Error message
 return response.send(500, 'Class does not exist', "application/json", '{ "error": "Class does not yet exist or a blank class was specified, please create the class first." }' );
}

//The var v wraps OrientVertex class
var v = graph.addVertex('class:' + className);

if (label) { v.setProperty('label', label); }
if (value) { v.setProperty('value', value); }
v.setProperty('createdBy', currentUserId);
v.setProperty('createdAt', currentTimeStamp);

//Commit
graph.commit();

return v;
```

Comment: Which version of ODB?

Comment: Version 2.0.7 of OrientDB